# regex replace: match variable number next to integer within substitute string

Tags: javascript, regex

How do do I create a substitute string with a match variable and integer against each other in my regex?

**Here are my two examples I am trying to solve.**

1)  ...by,Cheese/Night%20Out-Now,2...

2)  ...by,Cheese/2...

**Here is my regex attempt**

```
var re = /Cheese\/([\-\%_0-9a-z]+)?(,)?[0-9]+/i;
var subst = 'Cheese/$1$25';

var str1 = '...by,Cheese/Night%20Out-Now,2...';
var str2 = '...by,Cheese/2...';

var result1 = str1.replace(re, subst);
var result2 = str2.replace(re, subst);
```

**Here is my desired outcomes**

1)  ...by,Cheese/Night%20Out-Now,5...

2)  ...by,Cheese/5...

**Sandbox**

https://regex101.com/r/jT1tY6/3

Comment: [It works already](https://regex101.com/r/jT1tY6/3#javascript)

Comment: The issues I had with regex101.com was a result of being under the PHP tab, not javascript

Comment: Yes that's why I gave you a JS specific link of your own regex :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to already work. You can modify your regex by using one optional group here.

```
var re = /(Cheese\/(?:[\w%-]+,)?)[0-9]+/i
var subst = '$15';
```